# using inheritance to work around a bug in a library

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

Consider the following example:

```
struct Client
{
    void f()
    {
        s.registerCallback(std::bind(&Client::callback(), this));
        s.foo();
    }

    void callback()
    {
        std::cout << "called back" << std::endl;
    }

    // library class
    Service s;
};
```

Now, I have found a bug in `Service`, and want to put in a work-around in my client code. the workaround involves additional processing in `f()` and `callback()`. Let's also say that I `Service` in many parts of my code and I don't want to make the same changes everywhere.

Would a good solution be to simply subclass `Service` to a new class `ServiceWithWorkaround`, introduce the work-around logic in the overridden `foo()` and `registerCallback()` calls, and replace instances of `Service` with `ServiceWithWorkaround` wherever I need the workaround, until the vendor fixes the bug?

Assume that `Service` has quite an extensive interface and I do not want to use a decorator pattern and implement and forward the entire `Service` interface. Is there a better pattern that I can use here to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. I doubt we can give any concrete answer without a proper [mcve] as we don't know how `Service` works. What did the vendor say about this question when you asked them?

Comment: Let's just say the workaround is simple enough that I could have implemented it directly in `f()` and `callback()`. essentially involves caching some data in `f()` and processing that data in `callback()`. I could also do this workaround in a subclass of `Service`. I'm just not sure if inheritance is a good idea for this purpose, or if there are other recommended ways to go about something like that. Vendor is ok with us doing a workaround. I didn't tell them how we were going to design it.

Comment: As I say, we can't tell you without knowing how `Service` works, or what the workaround is. Maybe `Service` is safe for deriving in the way you plan; maybe it's not. You should work with the vendor on this. Only they can know for sure whether your planned workaround is valid, effective and safe. In the meantime, you have a known-safe workaround that can go in your own code...

Comment: Thanks. But writing a subclass of Service with the workaround in specific overridden functions is not like a "red flag" like that's a terrible idea then, right, from a design perspectve? Assuming of course the work around works as expected. And that this is temporary until the vendor patches the issue.

Comment: Again, there is just _no way to know_ from the outside. We can't see the nature of the workaround, how well it would slot into a new inheritance hierarchy for this type, or whether an inheritance hierarchy for this type is even viable.

Comment: There is no way to answer the question without you clarifying how `Service` works and your constraints.

Answer (score -1):

The (only) good solution is to fix the code. Inheritance is meant to *extend* a class's functionality, not to *alter* it. (This is reflected in the the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).)

Now, if you want some parts of the code to use the "fixed" functionality of `Service` ("Foo"), while others use the original functionality ("Bar"), it sounds like you should extract the common elements into a new base class of `Service`, and have two subclasses: `BarService` to provide the original functionality and `FooService` to provide the new functionality. Then any user of the class can pick which one they want. (Resist the urge to name the "original functionality" subclass `Service` to get around having to change references. Avoiding refactoring leads to crappy code.)

Comment: How can you have "a new base class" of someone else's class defined in some library?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings By changing that library.

Comment: By changing a library written by someone else whose source code you have no access to? Great plan.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Who says you don't have the source code? But in any case, if you can't/won't change the offending code, you do whatever hacks are most convenient. Preprocessor hacks, overwriting vtable entries, violating ODR, whatever. But none of it falls under the category of "design patterns", because it's *not about design*. It's just a hack, whether you (mis)use OO-related features of the language or (mis)use some other features.

Comment: If you had the source code and were happy to fix the issue in it, you wouldn't need a workaround ‍♂️‍♂️ You haven't answered the question.

Comment: this is a vendor product which code i do not have access to

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings In an ideal world you'd be right. But software developers often implement workarounds instead of fixes, even when either one would be possible, for various reasons (not all of them evil).

Comment: I'm sure they do, but that's not the question. If you want to encourage the OP to instead fix the root cause (even though they have now confirmed that they can't), that's a comment under the question at best. :)